# Como faço ajuste da lengenda para spatial lines no ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou plotando linhas sobre polígonos, mas quando tento inserir a legenda as linhas ficam ruins, como faço ajustar isso?

**Sem a Legenda**

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(mapa_mg) + 
  aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "white") +
  geom_path(color="grey50") +
  labs(y="latitude", x="longitude") +
  geom_polygon(data=mapa_rod, 
               mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
               color = cores[mapa_rod$idcores],
               fill="transparent",
               size = 1) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image: map1]

**Com a legenda**

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(mapa_mg) + 
  aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "white") +
  geom_path(color="grey50") +
  labs(y="latitude", x="longitude") +
  geom_polygon(data=mapa_rod, 
               mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
               color = cores[mapa_rod$idcores],
               fill="transparent",
               size = 1) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image: map2]

Comment: Resolvido:  Era só trocar geom_polygon por geom_path e fill por color referência ->                                                         [link](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/spatial-data-r/make-maps-with-ggplot-in-R/)

Comment: Adiciona a resposta como resposta para futuros visitantes se orientarem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solução**:

```
legenda1 = c("BR-040","BR-116","BR-262","BR-381")
cores = c('#d01c8b', 'yellow', '#e66101', 'blue')

library("ggplot2")
library('ggsn')
library("ggrepel")

ggplot(mapa_mg) +       
  aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "white") +
  geom_path(color="grey50") +
  labs(y="latitude", x="longitude") +

  geom_path(data=mapa_rod, 
               mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, color=factor(idcores)), size = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cores, labels = legenda1) +
  labs(color = 'Rodovia') +

  theme(legend.title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 10)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face = NULL, size = 9)) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="white", size=.5, linetype="dotted")) +
  theme(legend.position=c(0.11, 0.15)) +

  ggsn::scalebar(mapa_mg, dist = 100, st.size=3, height=0.01, dd2km = TRUE, model = 'WGS84') +
  ggsn::north(mapa_mg, symbol = 16, scale = 0.15) +

  coord_equal()
```

[image: map]